# How to achieve high speed with Laravel Broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-broadcast

I am working on Laravel application and I need to implement Broadcasting feature. Official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting suggests 3 ways:

1. Pusher.com --> Echo
2. laravel-websockets --> Echo
3. Redis --> Socket.Io --> Echo

Till now I have tried to use only Pushes.com solution as a simplest one. On my testes this solution delivers messages to users browsers with delay about 1 second. But 1 second is too long for me.

- What is normal delay for Laravel Broadcasting solutions?
- Which solution is the best for use?
- How to choose between solution 2 and 3?